# Bash not evaluating variable properly

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote simple commands that work when written in Makefile, but I found that it does not work in bash script.
Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA_DIR="mydir"
 
for i in `seq -f "%03g" 0 500`
 do
    cat ${DATA_DIR}/input_1/${i}.txt >> cat ${DATA_DIR}/input_0/${i}.txt
 done
```

The error message is

```
mydir/input_0/.txt not found.
```

The second variable appears to become empty.
I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Add `set -u` at top of script to consider use of unset variables as error.

Comment: BTW, did you intend to concatenate the input_1 and input_0 files into a file called `cat`, or is there a typo there?  A better [mcve] wouldn't read and write particular files - can you produce something that anyone can run without any setup and without affecting their system?

Comment: Since you're using Bash, consider `for i in {000..500}` as a more efficient alternative than running `seq` and gathering its output into a string.

Comment: Check that `${i}` for invisible characters - perhaps replace it with a copy-paste from the working side.  I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is `cat ${DATA_DIR}/input_1/${i}.txt >> cat ${DATA_DIR}/input_0/${i}.txt` supposed to do? Shouldn't you remove the second `cat`? Also, put double quotes around variable expansions. `cat "${DATA_DIR}/input_1/${i}.txt" >> "${DATA_DIR}/input_0/${i}.txt"`

Answer (score 4):

Your command is equivalent to (and more clearly written) as

```
cat ${DATA_DIR}/input_1/${i}.txt ${DATA_DIR}/input_0/${i}.txt >>cat
```

The redirection does not need to be at the end, but the command is easier to read if you put it there. Rewritten in this way, we see that you want to catenate the two input files and append the concatenated data to a file named `cat`. I don't think that you really want to do this, or at least I suggest that you give a better name to the output file (for instance `cat.txt`), but first of all you asked for the meaning of the error message:

The error message means, that either the directory `mydir/input_0` or the file `mydir/input_0/.txt` do not exist. You can verify this by doing in your script a `ls -ld mydir/*` before entering the loop.

In addition, it is strange that `i` is obviously empty at this point. This can't happen with standard `seq` and I can't reproduce it, so I would first check, whether you are using the correct `seq`: For debugging, do a `type seq` before entering the loop and verify that you see the correct path. Then I would check, whether the empty `i` shows up in the first or in the last iteration of the loop. Doing a `echo :$i:` inside the loop should be sufficient to clarify this. Finally, I would have a look at the script using an hex editor, in particular at the area around the `for` line. Do you see strange character codes, which don't belong there?